# my custom_post_type does not appear in my web page...how?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

i created a custom_post_type and created a post in there and it does not appear in my web page...

how can i call it to where i want?

normal post are called like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <div id="content-align">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
```

Comment: Well... where do you want it?

Comment: i wanted it in index

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to hook into `pre_get_posts` for the blog index. The following should only effect the blog index. That is what [`is_home()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) is for. Of course, you can edit the function to alter that behavior if you want.

```
function add_post_type_to_index_wpse_88317($qry) {
  if (is_home()) {
    $qry->set('post_type',array('post','movies_cp')); // plus any others you want.
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','add_post_type_to_index_wpse_88317');
```

That post type is from another question on this site somewhere. I used it because I could test it on my server. You will need to make that match the name you used to register your post type.

### Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query